# SQL group by: select value where another column has its min/max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group by one column, get both min and max of a second column, and (this is the tricky part!) get the value from a third column where the second column has its min value in the group.

Example:

MyTable:

```
ID     TS     GRP
==================
 1     20      A
 2     20      B
 3     10      A
 4     30      A
 5     10      B
 6     40      A
```

Desired result (ID should be the value from the record where TS has its minimum):

```
ID    MIN_TS   MAX_TS   GRP
============================
 3      10       40      A
 5      10       20      B
```

In general, the grouping query is very easy:

```
SELECT <???> AS ID, MIN(TS) AS MIN_TS, MAX(TS) AS MAX_TS, GRP
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY GRP
```

But what about the ID part? It doesn't work this way with grouping, right? But why? And what's the best workaround?

Comment: You need a JOIN to find that row(s).

Comment: What to do in case of ties? Or can't they occur (i.e. do you have a unique constraint on TS + GRP)?

Comment: You are right, that's the reason why it doesn't work with grouping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the aggregation in a subquery, then look up the ID for each group in another subquery:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT TOP(1) id FROM MyTable WHERE grp = agg.grp ORDER BY ts DESC) AS id,
  min_ts, max_ts, grp
FROM (SELECT min(ts) AS min_ts, max(ts) AS max_ts, grp
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY grp) agg
```

Or use window functions:

```
SELECT id, min_ts, max_ts, grp
FROM (SELECT 
        id,
        min(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) min_ts,
        max(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) max_ts,
        grp,
        row_number OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ts) rn
      FROM MyTable)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This query uses window functions to calculate `min_ts` and `max_ts` for each group, and then filters to only include the first row for each group (ordered by `ts`).

Comment: I prefer your second solution using the window functions.

Comment: Mind you, ranking functions are extremely slow on very large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for future comers...

I can propose another solution that's a bit different than the existing one, it's basically the same idea, but it's implemented in another way (and it's maybe a bit faster?).

So you can basically make all the grouping and aggregation in a sub query (using `WITH`), then use `INNER JOIN` between that query and your original table to get what you want, it would be something like this...

```sql
WITH values AS (
  SELECT
    MIN(ts) as min_ts,
    MAX(ts) AS max_ts,
    grp
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY grp
)

SELECT
  tb.id AS id,
  v.min_ts AS min_ts,
  v.max_ts AS max_ts,
  tb.grp AS grp
FROM MyTable tb
INNER JOIN values v ON v.grp = tb.grp AND v.min_ts = tb.ts;
```

This is a bit simpler, and a bit more intuitive (at least to me).

I have tested this on Postgres DB, and for the following data

```
 id | ts | grp 
----+----+-----
  7 |  5 | A
  3 | 10 | A
  1 | 20 | A
  5 | 30 | A
  4 | 10 | B
  2 | 20 | B
  6 | 30 | B
  8 | 60 | B
```

It gives the following results

```
 id | min_ts | max_ts | grp 
----+--------+--------+-----
  7 |      5 |     30 | A
  4 |     10 |     60 | B
```